# register_shutdown_function() php

Tags: php

I am new at php. I came to know about register_shutdown_function() in php. I have read about this function in php.net manual that when script finish execution this function calls. But i have a question

What if i put this function in namespace like

```
 namespace MyNamespace;
 register_shutdown_function("myHandler");  // this throws an error because it can't find function
 function myHandler() 
 { 
    // Some Code.
 }


 namespace MyNamespace;
 register_shutdown_function("MyNamespace\myHandler");  // this throws no error.
 function myHandler() 
 { 
    // Some Code.
 }
```

why this happens both register_shutdown_function() and myHandler() are in same namespace??

and if i put this namespace in different file and i include that file but i won't use this namespace 'MyNamespace' then does it execute?

Comment: What error did you get on `// this throws no error.`? Is your code one file or two? If it is two it should work.

Comment: it shows me this error 'Warning: register_shutdown_function(): Invalid shutdown callback 'ErrorHandelerHelper::errorHandler' passed in /var/www/workspace/6thAssignment/include/test.php on line 6 '   and i have tried for both putting in same file & different files it gives me same result but i don't understand why?.

Comment: You will get this error only if you do not pass a callable function see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/standard/tests/general_functions/bug32647.phpt and https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0d7a6388663b76ebed6585ac92dfca5ef65fa7af/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L5135

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `register_shutdown_function()` has nothing to do with that. It's about how PHP parses string callbacks. See this sample:

```
namespace MyNamespace;
$data = ['foo', 'bar'];
$data = array_filter($data, 'myHandler'); //warning, while 'MyNamespace\myHandler' is ok
register_shutdown_function("MyNamespace\myHandler");
function myHandler() 
{
        return 1;
}
```

-i.e. you must qualify your callback with it's full path to use that inside string-callbacks. That's because if you're specifying callback as a string, it becomes like *global* context (i.e. no more related to current namespace context) - because string itself does not contain any references to current namespace scope, it's just a string and nothing more.

Comment: yes i got your conclusion but my question is that if both register_shutdown_function() and myHandler() are within same namespace then why it asks for full path of the 'myHandler()'??

Comment: @SohilDesai I've mentioned that. Your string callback is still a simple string and it can not contain any references to current context. String is just a string and nothing more - that's why you have to specify full path within it.

Answer (score 1):

The shutdown function is probably called after all objects have been deconstructed, have you tried:

May be below code help full to you...

```
<?php
function shutdown()
{
    // This is our shutdown function, in 
    // here we can do any last operations
    // before the script is complete.

    echo 'Script executed with success', PHP_EOL;
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help i have read this example at php.net manual but it is not helping.